# Хлебные крошки: как правильно использовать gem Gretel?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Не получается правильно его использовать.
Если у кого нибудь есть время, не могли бы написать на русском языке как его применять?

Я определённо что то не так делаю.

открываю **config/breadcrumbs.rb**

пишу туда:

```
 crumb :articles_all_name do
   link "name", articles_path
 end
```

открываю вьюшку **articles.html.erb**

пишу в самый верх страницы: <%= breadcrumb :articles_all_name %>

В результате в месте вывода крошки номер его объекта что ли:

```
#<Gretel::Renderer:0x545cdd8>
```

Answer (score 2):

Для использования гема необходимо добавить в Gemfile запись

```
gem "gretel"
```

Выполнив установку гема при помощи bundle install, можно инициализировать гем в проекте командой

```
rails generate gretel:install
```

Впрочем это не обязательно, команда генерирует заготовку для конфигурационного файла config/breadcrumbs.rb, которую можно сформировать самостоятельно (кстати, файл допускается разбивать на части и хранить в папке config/breadcrumbs).

В конфигурационном файле может быть несколько блоков, если внутри блока вы не определяете метод parent - блок считается корневым.

```
crumb :root do
  link "home", root_path
end

crumb :articles_all_name do
  link "name", articles_path
  parent :root
end
```

Теперь когда у вас все готово, можно подключать хлебные крошки к представлению. **Обратите внимание**, что для этого используется два метода, которые отличаются лишь числом: **breadcrumb** и **breadcrumbs**.

breadcrumbs (во множественном числе) задает формат хлебных крошек, как правило, его размещают в layout-е

```
<%= breadcrumbs pretext: "Вы тут: ", separator: " &rsaquo; " %>
```

В представлении в articles.html.erb размещается метод breadcrumb (в единственном числе), который сообщает путь до текущей страницы для breadcrumbs.

```
<% breadcrumb :articles_all_name %>
```

**Обратите внимание**, следует использовать **<%**, а не **<%=**. Ваша задача тут не выводить путь, а сообщить его breadcrumbs из layout-а.